# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage. TypeMappingSourceDependencies'

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I ran into the following error after my .net core project and its dependencies to the latest framework version (version 6+) when I was running any CLI command (such as `dotnet ef add` for instance):

`Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage. TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal. MySQLTypeMappingSource'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article which helped solved the issue: https://www.svrz.com/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-storage-typemappingsourcedependencies/

Adding this class to the project:

```
public class MysqlEntityFrameworkDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL();

        new EntityFrameworkRelationalDesignServicesBuilder(serviceCollection)
            .TryAddCoreServices();
    }
}
```

Adding this class solved for me.